# Neo4j Hello World Tutorial and webadmin

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm learning `Neo4j` via their [tutorials](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-java-embedded-hello-world.html).

I've got the `Hello World` tutorial working, but I'm wondering how to view the graph in the webadmin on localhost. I assume the first step is not to call removeData() and shutDown(), but just doing that isn't accomplishing it.

Basically, how can I run the the `Hello World` tutorial and then view/query it through webadmin?

Comment: If you're talking about using it while your project is on, there used to be a tutorial over here http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-embedded.html but I don't know where it went. I also don't remember the exact steps, but you need to add all the jars from system/lib to the classpath of your project and call a method of sorts. I don't have access to my PC right now to see how I made it, but if tomorrow you're still needing help, I can properly answer this.

Comment: Ok, posted my answer now. Not quite sure if you meant opening webadmin inside your project or not, but there it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Calling shutdown won't destroy your data. Can you share your code?
Also make sure your Neo4j server points to the same database used in your code i.e. DB_PATH from

graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH )

You can check this property *org.neo4j.server.database.location* in the file neo4j-server.properties found in the conf directory of your neo4j installation.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to access webadmin after your project stopped, like Luanne said, calling `shutdown()` will not erase anything, so you can go to `your-neo4j-installation-path/conf/neo4j-server.properties` and change the `org.neo4j.server.database.location` property to the same path you used in your code.

From the link you gave, that would be the path you put here:

> graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH );

After that you call `your-neo4j-installation-path/bin/neo4j start` (or neo4j.bat if you're using windows) and it should work.

But if what you want is to make webadmin available to you while your project is running, with the embedded server, then here is what you should do.

First, to make neo4j embedded work, you should put all the jars in `your-neo4j-installation-path/lib/` in the buildpath of your project, right?

To make webadmin available while the embedded database is in use, you should ***also*** put all the jars in `your-neo4j-installation-path/system/lib/` in the buildpath of your project.

Then you will create the GraphDatabaseService as usual.

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDb; 
graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
```

Then you will make an instance of the WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper class.

```
WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper srv = new WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper((GraphDatabaseAPI) graphdb);
```

(The constructor receives a GraphDatabaseAPI, which is now deprecated, so we make a GraphDatabaseService and put a cast when passing it to `WrappingNeoServerBoorstrapper()` )

Last but not least, you use the method `start()`.

```
srv.start();
```

And voilá.

If you want it to stop, just call `srv.stop()`

I suggest you add a `registerShutdownHook()` method (like [this tutorial](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-setup.html) suggests) and put the `stop()` method in there.

```
private static void registerShutdownHook( final GraphDatabaseService graphDb )
{
    // Registers a shutdown hook for the Neo4j instance so that it
    // shuts down nicely when the VM exits (even if you "Ctrl-C" the
    // running application).
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook( new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            srv.stop();
            graphDb.shutdown();
        }
    } );
}
```

And that's it.