# Can not explore database created by an embedded neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I encounter a strange problem.

I created an database using embedded neo4j whose path is "/Users/bondwong/Documents/workspace/pamela/target/data/pamela.db".

Here is the Spring configuration:

```
<bean id="graphDbBuilder" factory-bean="graphDbFactory"
    factory-method="newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder">
    <constructor-arg value="target/data/pamela.db" />
</bean>
```

Then I changed this line of neo4j-server.properties:

```
org.neo4j.server.database.location=/Users/bondwong/Documents/workspace/pamela/target/data/pamela.db
```

After that, I used curl to test my system, which showed all is good. Here is the result of getting a node whose id is 9:
[image]

However, when I fired up the server, and use the browser to see the data, nothing shows up: 
[image]

Here is the location, it is the same as the one in the Spring XML configuration file:
[image]

Here is the :sysinfo result:
[image]

Here is the jUnit test and its result, showing that it actually insert the data:

```
package repositoryTest;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.bond.pamela.domain.Diary;
import com.bond.pamela.domain.factory.DiaryFactory;
import com.bond.pamela.persistence.DirayRepository;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "/applicationContext.xml" })
public class DiaryRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    DirayRepository repository;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void testSaveDiary() {
        Diary diary = (Diary) DiaryFactory.getInstance().create(
                new HashMap<String, Object>());
        repository.save(diary);

        Diary retrivedDiary = repository.findOne(diary.getGraphId());
        assertEquals(diary, retrivedDiary);
    }

}
```

[image]

I think it should work, someone knows what is wrong? and how to fix it. Thx!

Comment: Only one process can access the database at a time. The Neo4j server shouldn't even start.

Comment: What does :sysinfo say about the database?

Comment: @MichaelHunger u mean I should shutdown the neo4j server?But I wanna see the data, u have other ideas? I stopped tomcat, in which I my application runs, and tried leave the neo4j sever open alone, and still, there was nothing.

Comment: @MichaelHunger edit my post adding the result of :sysinfo

Comment: then the directory was not correct for the server, or it actually didn't insert the data because your java program couldn't access it. Are you swallowing exceptions somewhere?

Comment: @MichaelHunger I believe that the data was inserted, I unit tested it, in which I create node and put it into database and then retrieved it for comparison.

Comment: Are you sure you committed the transaction correctly? `Transaction tx = db.beginTx(); tx.success(); tx.close();`

Comment: Oh, you're using Spring? **[ ] you know that the spring test runner automatically rolls back all transactions at the end of the test?**

Comment: @MichaelHunger I know that, I set up two kinds of test. One is using Spring, which proves that data did successfully insert into database. Another is starting up the server, and using curl to call the REST api to test. The second test uses a database directory other than the first one, which means on Spring test and data should be right in the database. Although the curl test shows that I can insert data and retrieve data, nothing shows up when using browser.

Comment: Then you have to make sure your "curl" test also sends data to the running server. And commits transactions correctly.

Comment: @MichaelHunger I am sure that curl test commits transactions correctly, maybe I can try one of the means u provide in your answers: ) thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your java code as [server extension](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html)

or use [WrappingBootstrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26794676/728812) for the time being.
Or rather use [ServerControls from Neo4j-Harness](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions-testing.html) for testing

When creating the data, are you sure you committed the transaction correctly?

```
Transaction tx = db.beginTx();
// create data
tx.success(); 
tx.close();
```

or better

```
try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
  // create data
  tx.success(); 
}
```

Comment: we are mainly using the  WrappingBootstrapper for debugging but I saw it was deprecated and even removed on the next release - are there plans to add a "query browser" or something like that to the embedded server or that the official suggestion is to stop using the embedded mode?